# distcp is not executing

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distcp, s3distcp

i am trying to copy data from one hdfs cluster to another using distcp command.following is the command which i submitted

hadoop distcp hdfs://sourcenamenodehostname:50070/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/distcptest.txt hdfs://destinationnamenodehostname:50070/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs

while submitting this i got error message . please go through the error message and guide me to the correct way.

---

19/02/27 04:28:19 INFO tools.OptionsParser: parseChunkSize: blocksperchunk false
19/02/27 04:28:20 ERROR tools.DistCp: Invalid arguments:
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category READ is not supported in state standby. Visit https://s.apache.org/sbnn-error
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.StandbyState.checkOperation(StandbyState.java:88)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$NameNodeHAContext.checkOperation(NameNode.java:1835)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkOperation(FSNamesystem.java:1515)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:4448)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getFileInfo(NameNodeRpcServer.java:912)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.getFileInfo(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:862)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2281)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2277)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1924)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2275)

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:230)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:788)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.setTargetPathExists(DistCp.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:493)
```

Invalid arguments: Operation category READ is not supported in state standby. Visit https://s.apache.org/sbnn-error
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.StandbyState.checkOperation(StandbyState.java:88)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$NameNodeHAContext.checkOperation(NameNode.java:1835)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkOperation(FSNamesystem.java:1515)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:4448)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getFileInfo(NameNodeRpcServer.java:912)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.getFileInfo(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:862)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2281)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2277)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1924)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2275)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that one of the namenode (the source) is not healthy and not accepting inbound connections to modify state or new writes. See this -

```
Invalid arguments: Operation category READ is not supported in state standby.
```

Comment: so you are suggesting me to use the other namenode?

Comment: Two things which you should be doing here - Why is your namenode not healthy? And yes you can use the other HA node to run distCP

Comment: Raunak, i tried with both namenodes but still it is showing the same error.

Comment: i tried with hadoop distcp hdfs://ipaddress of the source namenode:50070/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/distcptest.txt hdfs://ipaddressof the destnation namenode:50070/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs

Comment: This is what am getting when i submit the above command. please help me to sort out this issue.

PriviledgedActionException as:hdfs/hostname.of.the.sourceserver@EDA.domain.COM (auth:KERBEROS) cause:java.io.EOFException
19/02/27 06:14:34 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : java.io.EOFException

Comment: What happens when you do kinit and than klist. Are you able to then run something like "HDFS DFS -LS /USER"